# Is it possible to use non-entity field in Specification?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have code:

```
public class CustomFilter<T> implements Specification<EntityHE> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<EntityHE> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        Predicate hasTenant = cb.equal(root.get("custom_field"), "value");
        predicates.add(hasTenant);

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    }
}

@Entity(name = "entity")
@Table(name = "table")
public class EntityHE {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "kind")
    private String kind;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "modified")
    private Instant modified;

    public EntityHE(){};
}
```

I can invocation error because I don't have field "custom_field" in my entity. 
Is it possible to filter by this specification without adding "custom_field" as a field in my entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's not possible. Because the specification will be used in a JPA Criteria API query and there you can only query for mapped attributes.